# New PC Build - No Beeps and No Display

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, post

### Issue

- No USB Power
- No Display
- No Beeps
- Chasis Fans Not Working - *Used to work on previous build.*
- 1 of the PCI-E lanes does not light up.

### Troubleshooting Steps

- Try to boot using only one RAM stick, shuffled between all 4 RAM sticks and all slots.
- Boot PC without RAM, no beeps.
- Boot PC without RAM and Graphic Card, no beeps.
- Boot PC without RAM, Graphic Card and Storage Mediums, no beeps.

### Specifications

- ASUS STRIX X99 Gaming
- Intel Core i7-6800K
- Corsair Dominator Platinum (4 x 8GB)
- EVGA GTX 760 SC - *Imported from previous build.*
- Samsung 950 Pro PCI-E M2 SSD
- Samsung 850 Pro SSD x3 - *Imported from previous build.*
- Corsair HX-750

### Beeps

- 1 Short - VGA detected, Quick Boot set to Disabled, No Keyboard detected.
- 1 Long 2 Short - No Memory detected.
- 1 Long 3 Short - No VGA detected.
- 1 Long 4 Short - Hardware Failure.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix the issue or what's causing the issue?

Comment: You state one issue is no beeps, and then you list a collection of beeps.  Based on Issue and Troubleshooting, it sounds like a power problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I've tried a different PSU with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed faulty board, replaced and working.